string base64 on Android (nativescript)
I try to use
(1) atob() and btoa() - functions missing
(2) node Buffer - functions also missing
(3) native Android decoder - getBytes function missing
const bytes = password.getBytes("UTF-8")
let x = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(bytes,android.util.Base64.NO_WRAP)

what correct way?

My solution:
const bytes = this.convertStringToByteArray(password)
password = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(bytes,android.util.Base64.NO_WRAP)

convertStringToByteArray(buf: string): Array<any> {
    const ret = (Array as any).create("byte", buf.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < ret.length; i++) {
      ret[i] = (buf as any)[i];
    }
    return ret;
}

interesting, that Array create exactly java.lang.Object (bytes), not Javascript of course

